# Angluar 14 typed forms how to use inferred type

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

The typical way I use forms is

```
DummyComponent {
form: FormGroup;

constructor(formService:FormService) {
this.form = formService.initForm()
...
```

This way the type is lost since it is inferred during declaration. Any idea on how to use the inferred type when creating a form outside the component that is using it?

Answer (score 0):

inside the `formService` set the return type (`FormGroup`) to the method called `initForm`.

```
initForm(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
        firstName: new FormControl(''),
        lastName: new FormControl(''),
    });
}
```

Comment: @user13164053 does this answer fix your issue?